# Can there exist a single Turing machine complete for PTIME, or for $\#P_1$?

Tags: complexity-classes, counting-complexity, universal-computation

In ["The Complexity of Enumeration and Reliability Problems"](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0208032), Valiant mentions the existence of a single Turing machine that is complete for the class $\#P_1$ (i.e., $\#P$ with unary input). On page 419, he writes:

> it is sufficient to simulate just the following fixed TM, $M$, which
>   is clearly complete for $\#P_1$: on unary input $n$, $M$ first
>   verifies that ... and then simulates the $i$th machine in $\#TIME(n)$
>   on input $j$ (or vice versa)

I find the existence of such a machine surprising:

- Does there exist a machine complete for PTIME that can simulate any
  other PTIME machine. That is, a PTIME machine that takes a number $i$ and a string $s$ as input, and then executes the $i$th PTIME machine
  with input $s$?
- Would the existence of such a machine not lead to a
  contradiction, because it would have a complexity $O(n^k)$, which means that no PTIME machine can have complexity $O(n^{k+1})$.
- If this is indeed not possible for PTIME, why is it possible for $\#P_1$?

Comment: The machine can convert the unary input to binary, and work on it (the input length changes from $|x|$ to $\log |x|$).

Comment: If some machine solves a PTIME-complete problem $Q$ in $O(n^k)$ time, that doesn't mean that every problem $Q'$ in PTIME is also in $DTIME[n^k]$: the reduction of $Q'$ to $Q$ generally increases the size of the instance.